# Analytics allows me to populate report tables with data, but since the error occurs my reports fail to display

Tags: analytics

[I am using dhis2.28 version and we faced error related Analytics allows me to populate report tables with data, but since the error occurs my reports fail to display.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGEvW.jpg)

Please Find below attached screen shot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't paste links to images of your code or error messages. It would be much better to copy/paste your code/error messages into your question, including what line gives you that error. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please edit your question and improve formatting.